# How to get HTML data from a webpage and invoke the click event of the Next Page link using .NET when page is logged in

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I need to create a chrome extension to scrape date from LinkedIn, I will manually log in to LinkedIn. and run a search that will return multiple pages. I will then click on the chrome extension icon, At that point, the extension should read the content of the page (HTML) and invoke an HTTP post request to a Web API service that takes that data (`HTML`) as `string` and saves it as a file on disk. Then the extension should invoke the click event of the Next Page link and when the content loaded do the same. And keep going until the last page.

Comment: Can you share in more general terms what it is you're trying to accomplish? Also, I won't down vote your question, but please be more clear in your post, also mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: I need to to get HTML data when I'm logged in(LinkedIn search page)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `content script` for reading the html of a page:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: and what about Invoke Next Page link

Comment: querying the buttons and calling their `.click` method should work